# Oracle UNUSABLE Index Problem With Bulk Insertion

Tags: oracle, aws-dms

I have a postgresql database and I have **1TB** data. I want to migrate this data from postgresql to Oracle. I can handle it via DMS(Database Migration Service). When I migrate my data, Oracle indexes look like **UNUSABLE** then I try to rebuild it I got error because data is too big. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found why index state changed from **VALID** to **UNUSABLE** http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_indexes_invalid_unusable.htm

And solved on AWS DMS, set DMS Endpoints → Target(Oracle) → Modify → Endpoint settings → Key (`useDirectPathFullLoad`) Value(`false`). For more detail: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Oracle.html